# Is this a valid proof of Lagrange's theorem (finite case).

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

Let $G$ be finite and $H$ be a subgroup. We will show that the left cosets of $H$ partition $G$ and each coset has the same size.

> 1) Each element $g \in G$ belongs to the coset $gH$ since $g1=g$ and $1\in H$.

So every element lies in at least one coset.

> 2) We know show that each $g \in G$ lies in exactly one coset.

Suppose for a contradiction $g$ lies in more than one coset then $g \in aH$ and $g \in bH$ where $aH,bH$ are distinct left cosets. Then $g=ah_1$ and $g=bh_2$ so $ah_1=bh_2$ for some $h_1,h_2 \in H$.

Now $aH \subseteq bH$ since if $ah \in aH$ then $ah=bh_2h_1^{-1}h \in bH$. Likewise $bH \subseteq aH$ so $aH=bH$ a contradiction.

So each $g \in G$ lies in exactly one coset.

Hence the cosets form a partition of $G$.

> 3) For each $g \in G$ the coset $gH$ has the same order as $H$.

To see this establish a function $\phi:gH \rightarrow H$ by $\phi(gh)=h$. This is clearly a bijection.

So $|G|=\text{Number of cosets} \times \text{Size of each coset}=[G:H]|H|$ and so $|H| \mid |G|$.

> Is this proof valid?

Comment: What do you mean "finite case"? Lagrange's theorem is only applicable to finite groups, since "divides the order" only makes sense when "order" is a number.

Comment: There's just a small issue with your argument that $aH\subseteq bH$.  You wrote $ah = bh_2h_{1}^{-1}$, where I think it should be $ah = bh_2h_{1}^{-1}h$.

Comment: By finite case I meant there is some kind of extension that the index is infinite for infinite groups.

Comment: @James Yes you are correct that was just a mistake when writing it out. Is everything else sound though? Thanks!

Comment: Everything sounds good to me. Though it may be easier to justify the last point by considering $\phi : H\to gH$ defined by $\phi(h)= gh$. It would then be easier to justify that :1. It is well-defined, 2. It is bijective

Comment: Yes, except that, as @Max also noted, a bit more justification that your map $\phi$ is a well-defined bijection would be in order.

Answer (score 2):

*To summarise the comments . . .*

Your proof is fine, except that I recommend you consider $$\begin{align}
\varphi: H&\to gH \\
h&\mapsto gh,
\end{align}$$

then justify that $\varphi$ is a well-defined bijection; it's much easier than your $\phi$.

Also, Lagrange's Theorem only applies to finite groups.